# How to understand usage information of linux commands?

Tags: command-line-arguments

Example: what does it mean, '[]' and '[[]]' options ?

```
usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Comment: Anything between [ brackets ] are options, not required. Double [[ backets ]], like `[[user@]host2:]` means that the whole thing is optional, but if you do specify a host for file2, you can also specify a user.

Comment: Also, note that on Linux it's common that options with a single - dash are single character options, so you don't need to use all 1246BCpqrv options in one go, you can just use `-p -r` (or `-pr` for short) for example. For more info on what these options do, consult the man page `man scp`

Comment: `a | b` means you can use `a` or `b`

Comment: If you try to view a manpage and it waffles on about being a `BUILTIN` command (see what I mean with `man alias` or `man history`), then use `help` instead, e.g. `help alias`

Answer (score 0):

The stuff between square brackets is usually optional. Hence, you *don't* need to provide a `-B` option for example.

*Nested* brackets are for optional things *within* optional things and you can see the difference in the `-c` and file specification:

- The `[-c cipher]` is optional but, if you provide `-c`, you must *also* provide the `cipher` bit. The entire thing within the brackets is a single atomic unit, either there or not there.
- For `[[user@]host1:]file1`, the `file1` bit is absolutely needed because there are no bracket around it. You can optionally prefix that with a remote location specifier. If you do, the `host1:` bit is required but the `user@` bit is optional. So, any of `file1`, `host1:file1`, or `user@host1:file1` is allowed.